# Pandas vs Numpy Speed

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

With Pandas using Numpy under the hood I was curious as to why straight numpy code (509 ms) was 12x faster than doing the same operation with a dataframe (6.38 s) in the example below?

```
# function with numpy arrays
def f_np(freq, asd):
    for f in np.arange(21.,2000.,1.):
        fi = freq/f
        gi =  (1+fi**2) / ((1-fi**2)**2 + fi**2) * asd
        df['fi'] = fi
        df['gi'] = gi
        # process each df ...

# function with dataframe
def f_df(df):
    for f in np.arange(21.,2000.,1.):
        df['fi'] = df.Freq/f
        df['gi'] = (1+df.fi**2) / ((1-df.fi**2)**2 + df.fi**2) * df.ASD
        # process each df ...


freq =  np.arange(20., 2000., .1)
asd = np.ones(len(freq))
df = pd.DataFrame({'Freq':freq, 'ASD':asd})    

%timeit f_np(freq, asd)
%timeit f_df(df)

509 ms ± 723 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
6.38 s ± 20.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: generally creation of Pandas Series/DataFrame has small overhead for naming/indexing. Also, `df['fi'] = someSeries` has some significant overhead due to index alignment. Same goes for all other arithmetic operators. All that adds up.

Comment: Adding .values to the dataframes in the f_df function (like, df.fi.values**2) speeds things up considerably (only 1.5x slower), but I would have thought that pandas might have handled that optimization (reducing to numpy array) behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the difference in speed is because of "some operation with a dataframe" in this specific case? I think the difference in speed is attributed to the fact that you created `fi` and `gi` variables and assigned the variables on the columns in the first example, but you didn't do that in the second example. The results were similar when I assigned a variable in both.

```
import pandas as pd,numpy as np
# function with numpy arrays
def f_np(freq, asd):
    for f in np.arange(21.,2000.,1.):
        fi = freq/f
        gi =  (1+fi**2) / ((1-fi**2)**2 + fi**2) * asd
        df['fi'] = fi
        df['gi'] = gi
        # process each df ...

# function with dataframe
def f_df(df):
    for f in np.arange(21.,2000.,1.):
        fi = freq/f
        gi =  (1+fi**2) / ((1-fi**2)**2 + fi**2) * asd
        df['fi'] = fi
        df['gi'] = gi
        # process each df ...


freq =  np.arange(20., 2000., .1)
asd = np.ones(len(freq))
df = pd.DataFrame({'Freq':freq, 'ASD':asd})    

%timeit f_np(freq, asd)
%timeit f_df(df)
#562 ms ± 9.23 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
#569 ms ± 17.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: as written, there is no difference between your `f_np` and `f_df` **in the code**.

Comment: But, the `f_df` function is calling a dataframe with pandas and the `f_np` function is calling a numpy array, so isn't the difference and ultimately the question more relevant later in these lines of `code: freq =  np.arange(20., 2000., .1)`
`asd = np.ones(len(freq))`
`df = pd.DataFrame({'Freq':freq, 'ASD':asd})`

Comment: The whole point was to show the difference when calculating with a dataframe column as opposed to a strict numpy array.  In your second function the dataframe that is passed in is not used in the calculations, only in assignment.